# How to write a complex order by query

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL on which I need to perform a select and then order it by a fairly complex logic. Here is an example of my logic:

```
if(column_a is not null && column_a > 0){
   var_a = column_a
else
   var_a = 1;

if(column_a is not null){
   var_b = column_b
else
   var_b = 0

if(column_c is not null){
   var_c = column_c
else
   var_c = column_d
```

ORDER BY (var_b*var_c)/var_a

So basically, I want to do something along the lines of SELECT * from mytable WHERE parameter = value ORDER BY variable_to_order_by . I would have to use some formula for variable_to_order_by, but I can't find any way of doing it which would not involve eight separate CASE WHERE statements, and that seems extremely messy. Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Mysql doesn't know anything about your business logic if you don't point it about the one. So you should use case when .. then clause.

Comment: You need to provide a more specific example with data. I don't really see what you are trying to obtain.

Comment: Furthermore, you order by elements from your database. I don't understand what you try to order by.

Comment: If any business logic to be added into mysql , then Only option is `Mysql Store procedures` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: I understand that I order by elements from my database, I was trying to use pseudocode to explain the logic I'm trying to achieve with my ordering. Basically all the values are in various columns. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a down and dirty way, you can use functions in an `order by` clause. In specific, you can use the `if` and `ifnull` functions. Therefore, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY IF(some_value IS NOT NULL AND some_value RLIKE '^[[:digit:]]+$', some_value, other_value)
       - (column_baz + IF(foo > bar, a, b))/(IFNULL(yet_another_value, 0) + IF(foo > bar, a, b))
```

(where the regular expression may have to be more complex if you want to include all reals instead of just integers, if you don't want to include a string starting with 0, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

a complex case/where structure is really what you need, so the mess is in the syntax. if you want to make the query more elegant, check out the [Adding New Functions to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html) section of the reference manual. then you'll have something like this:

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE parameter = value 
ORDER BY meaningfull_name_of_logic(
    foo, bar, some_value, other_value, yet_another_value, column_baz, a, b
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to tidy things up:

```
SELECT my_table.*,
  IF( foo > bar, a, b ) AS var_a,
  IF( some_value IS NOT NULL AND
        is_numeric( some_value ), some_value, other_value ) AS var_b,
  IFNULL( yet_another_value, 0 ) AS var_c
FROM my_table
ORDER BY var_b - (column_baz + var_a)/(var_c + var_a)
```

There will be 3 extra columns in your results that you should ignore. There are other ways to do this to avoid the 3 extra columns like using variables `@var_a :=` but that will have its own messiness, I prefer the above method.